# Android How to send DirectMessage using Twitter4j lib?

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

I'm using Twitter4j lib. I'm unable to send direct message to my followers.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DirectMessage message = null;
            try {

                message = twitter.sendDirectMessage(friendId, messsage);
                Log.d(" *** Twiiter Sent message **** ", "Sent Message is : "
                        + message.getText() + " \t Sender name: "
                        + message.getRecipientScreenName());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

I'm getting following exception:

404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
message - Sorry, that page does not exist
code - 34

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:

11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=9bf58966 or
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=17d1fbfd
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[9bf58966-17d1fbfd], statusCode=404, message=Sorry, that page does not exist, code=34, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:2004)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.sendDirectMessage(TwitterImpl.java:368)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at com.dman.tweetfragment.Fragments.MainFragment$6.run(MainFragment.java:993)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/System.err(1990):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-13 16:46:55.481: W/dalvikvm(1990): threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6296288)

Please provide your valuable suggestions here. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you All. I found answer. 
We have to pass **twitter user screenName instead of screenId**. screenId not works for me. I tried with screenName. It works fine.

```
 message = twitter.sendDirectMessage(friendscreenName, messsage);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your `friendId`. It must be `Long`. If it `String` then user's `screenName` must be used.